# I can't declare a map

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, dictionary, iso

So in my cpp file I'm trying to declare a map as follows:

```
map<string, vector<myStruct>> myMap;
```

At the top of my file I have written `using namespace std` and I also have `#include <string>`
.

However I'm getting these weird errors:

error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘map’ with no type

I don't know how to fix it. If I write `#include <map>` that just causes the compiler to freak out.

Comment: See the "Defined in header" note at the top [of this document](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map), then include that. And as mentioned in several answers, *don't* put `using namespace std;` in your header files. It's just a bad idea.

Answer (score 4):

do you have `#include <map>`? rest looks valid,
however you might need to add a space if your C++ standard is not C++11:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

map<string, vector<myStruct> > myMap;
                           ^^^
```

even better not use namespace std:

```
#include <map>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::map<std::string, std::vector<myStruct> > myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You should also include [`<map>`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/header/map). [`std::map`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map) is introduced through this header.

Furthermore, [**`using namespace std`** is considered a bad practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1452721/why-is-using-namespace-std-considered-a-bad-practice-in-c). You should either have a `using` statement or use the prefix the name with `std::` to denote a fully-qualified identifier:

```
#include <map>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

std::map<std::string, std::vector<myStruct>> myMap;
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to include `map` header file.

```
  #include <map>
```

Meanwhile, in case you are not using C++11, you need a space:

```
 map<string, vector<myStruct> > myMap;
                           //^^
```

Answer (score 0):

Note, the lack of a using statement ;)

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <map>

#include <iostream>

typedef int myStruct;

std::map<std::string, std::vector<myStruct>> myMap;

int
main()
{
  std::vector<myStruct> testMe = { 1, 2, 3};
  myMap["myTest"] = testMe;
  std::cout << myMap.size() << std::endl;
  return(0);
}
```

Comment: @tacp: Good point, depending on the compiler the >> may need to be > >. This compiled cleanly (and ran) using gcc 4.7.2.